# Windows update wont run windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

i have a windows 7 machine with service pack 1 installed. I am trying to update Windows. But  when i click the "check for updates", nothing happens. I had run chkdsk which returns a clear screen. I had also run sfc scan which showed a corrupt file which couldn't be repaired but it wasn't to do with windows update. I have also manually tested that the windows update service starts and stops which it does. i have also renamed the windows update temporary folder but it is still not working.I had also did virus as well as malware scan.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It may be connected to Update Service not working correctly. Have you read this article: [How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058/en)

Comment: no i will go through it now thanks. do you recommend the manual one or auto

Comment: I only used Manual one so I cannot say if Automatic way is better or not.

Comment: ok i have run that it it has returned an error.

Repair missing or corrupt files Completed 
 
SFC Output 
Output: Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service

Comment: should i do the manual registering of the files now to see if that fixes the corupption

Comment: SFC tool with /SCANNOW could help you repair system files. https://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Comment: i have now run though the steps manually it is missing 13 dlls. i can list them if its easier for you

Comment: tried that it says it cannot repair the errors

Comment: :( That sounds bad. Maybe you should consider repairing the System (F8 during boot). But that may result in "unregistering/uninstalling" some of your software. Maybe someone else will come up with better solution.

Comment: im going to try that now was hoping i didn't have to do it but looks like i do

Comment: ok so i rebooted ran f8 repair whch crashed and asked me to put cd in repair which i have done. what do i do no run startup repair or go to command prompt

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer for any errors?

Comment: this is my event viewer report.   Windows update  could not be installed because of error 3355443783 "" (Command line: ""C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\Users\administrator\Downloads\Windows6.1-KB947821-v31-x64.msu"        ")

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking.com
 Windows Repair (All in One) v2.1.1 Released

```
 Download install
 Uncheck everything and then just check **windows update**

 allow it to run and reboot
 Then run Windows Update again see if it works.
```

Answer (score 0):

If 1st suggestion fails

```
 run services.msc
 Turn Windows Update off
```

delete the **SoftwareDistribution** folder in the **Windows** Folder c:\windows

Turn Windows Update back on

Run Windows Update again